# Thread allocation per CPU cores (Windows only)

Tags: windows, multithreading

I am an amateur programmer so please bear with me.
I am about to write a plug-in for a game (for Windows OS) which would run in the background during gaming. Since the plugin will spawn threads which execution is CPU intensive and game's execution on different CPU cores can vary a lot, the plugin could only be executed on PCs with multiple cores which have a load lower then certain limit. 
I figured out how to monitor the CPU load per each core, but i still have a question:
Should the plugin handle allocating the threads to the cores with the lowest load or i can let the system handle that for me?
Would 1st solution be better for the game's performance?

Comment: _Pretty please_ **do not try to handle CPU core loads, memory loads, thread loads** etc. **by hand**, but leave it to the OS, **even** - and it is kind of important - **if you can come up with your seemingly better solution**. The reason I'm asking you to act like this is the following: _Imagine if more than one program does this!_ Imagine that they are **constantly changing** their behavior according to the load of the system, and they end up **using lots of CPU time** to adapt to a constantly changing system load. Do you see why you should not do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing your code for windows in Visual studio 2010, then I suggest you look at concurrency runtime available.
[Concurrency Runtime in Visual C++ 2010](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80825/Concurrency-Runtime-in-Visual-C-2010)

> Should the plugin handle allocating the threads to the cores with the
> lowest load or i can let the system handle that for me?

You can let the system handle that for you if you can design the system right. Also your code need not change based on number of cores as such detail is captured by the runtime and the number of threads that are spawned is proportional to the number of cores.

Comment: (s)he not on "can", but **should** leave this sort of resource management to the underlying system for the following reason:  Imagine if more than one program does this! Imagine that they are constantly changing their behavior according to the load of the system, and they end up using lots of CPU time to adapt to a constantly changing system load. Do you see why you should not do this?